# Selected category doesn't remain active after clicking

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, categories

I have a website which is showing products online. In it, I have categories and subcategories listed. When I'm clicking on a category, it doesn't remain active/selected. I have a `class="active"` which is added to the selected category when clicked but it doesn't expand on selection.

This is my website www.sitimobil.mk. The example site is www.fixit.mk

On the left side you have the categories and subcategories.

```
<?php
$qKategori = ("SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE kprind = 0");
$rKategori = mysqli_query($dbc, $qKategori);
if ($rKategori) {
    while ($exKat = mysqli_fetch_array($rKategori, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $emrikategorise = $exKat['kemri'];
        $idkategori     = $exKat['kid'];
        $idprind        = $exKat['kprind'];
?>  
    <li><a href="#"><?= $emrikategorise; ?></a>
    <ul <?php
        if ($_GET['kid'] == $idkategori) {
            echo 'class="active"';
        }
?>>
    <?php
        $qPrind = ("SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE kprind = '" . $idkategori . "'");
        $rPrind = mysqli_query($dbc, $qPrind);
        while ($prind = mysqli_fetch_array($rPrind)) {
?>
    <li><a href="kategori.php?kid=<?= $prind['kid'] ?>&kprind=<?= $prind['kprind'] ?>" <?php
            if ($_GET['kid'] == 48) {
                echo 'class="active"';
            }
?>><?= $prind['kemri'] ?></a></li>
    <?php
        }
        mysqli_free_result($rPrind);
?>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
    mysqli_free_result($rKategori);
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to add active class for that. get data from URL and apply class on <li> tag

Comment: I have a class="active", but when I click on the category, it doesn't expand on that category. Can you find something how to do this?

Comment: I have edited the title and contents to better explain your problem and also formatted the code block. Please have a look at [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information regarding code formatting. Well formatted code is easier to read and debug. If you are getting any specific error messages, please edit it into the question because that would help in debugging.